# FLV video not playing in Cooliris embed wall

Tags: rss, youtube, flv, cooliris

I have a PHP file that generates a Media RSS file for the embedded wall. It reads images and video from our Amazon S3 bucket and signs the URLs before creating the RSS feed.

When the wall loads, images display perfectly. Where there should be video there is only an empty black square, when the video is clicked - still only an empty square. However when I click on 'Start Slideshow' the video plays ok. When the video finishes it will load another image/video and this displays fine. I assume when i click a video thumbnail the video should start?

Also cannot get Youtube videos to play unless I use [this solution](http://developer.cooliris.com/dev_forum/comments.php?DiscussionID=137&page=1#Item_0) found on the cooliris developer forum

Anyone else notice this behaviour and have any advice / solution?

thanks

------------------------------- UPDATE ---------------------------------------------------

I have now added video thumbnails that should be showing and this shows the play icon but does not display the thumbnail jpeg. I use PHP to generate the rss feed as follows -

```
echo
            '
                <item>
                    <title>'.urldecode($subject).'</title>  
                    <media:content type="video/x-flv"  url="'.$file_name.'"/>
                    <media:thumbnail url="'.$file_name_thumb.'"/>       
                    <cooliris:data><![CDATA[
                    {
                        "mediatype" : "'.$row['file_type'].'",
                    }
                    ]]></cooliris:data>
                </item>
            ';
```

And a similar way for images. Both image thumbnails and fullsize images display without problem. When I enter the link to the video thumbnail into a browser address bar the image is returned OK.

Images and video are loaded from different buckets in S3 storage and I have checked cross domain policy files and they look ok to me, but could this be a problem? Like I say though the video plays ok when cooliris is in slideshow mode.

Heres a [link](http://crufts.burstfire.net/stephenTest/cooliris_embed.php) to a test page that shows the problem.

Comment: If you could post a link to your site with the problem, I can probably help you in debugging it.

Comment: Thanks, Ive added a link to a test page in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embedded wall should support FLV. If you have a test page you can share with us, we can help you debug.

EDIT:
The video does not render in 3D because there isn't a crossdomain.xml file hosted at your video site. That is, transcodedvideo.s3.amazonaws.com/crossdomain.xml/… needs to allow *.cooliris.com access. This is a limitation with the 3D library we use (PaperVision 3D). It works in slideshow mode because we simply add the 2D video to the Flash stage, without rendering it in 3D. We may revisit this in the future, so thanks for bringing up this issue.

Ron Yeh 
Cooliris Developer

Comment: Hi thanks - heres a link to a test page. I have not been creating video thumbs so use a single image for videos. When you click the play button at the bottom of the page videos play no problem, and when you double-click on the video they also play ok. Just not when you click once, in other cooliris examples I have seen the video starts to play when it is selected (single click). Heres the url - http://crufts.burstfire.net/stephenTest/cooliris_embed.php Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Can you also tell me how I can add a button to toggle fullscreen mode on/off rather than right clicking to bring up the context menu? thanks

Comment: I've updated the question with more detail. My scripts for video conversion now generate video thumbnails so these are now being included in the RSS feed being sent to cooliris.

Comment: Hi, in my debug flash log, I see a bunch of errors re: not being able to load the thumbnails. The URLs are of the form: http://transcodedvideo.s3.amazonaws.com/http://79.125.12.131/uploads/video/.....
and they return XML error documents like: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Key>http://79.125.12.131/uploads/video/30645_v1.wmv&amp;mpaction=convert format=flv width=320</Key><RequestId>28E941C277C4719E</RequestId><HostId>UDfAn3+Y48iGh8z5n0/FcPHqFNWm6OF55oCqFJWQTVPn+XfWDspz2E/mtTskjoyN</HostId></Error>

Comment: The video does not render in 3D because there isn't a crossdomain.xml file hosted at your video site. That is, http://transcodedvideo.s3.amazonaws.com/crossdomain.xml needs to allow *.cooliris.com access. This is a limitation with the 3D library we use (PaperVision 3D).

It works in slideshow mode because we simply add the 2D video to the Flash stage, without rendering it in 3D.

We may revisit this in the future, so thanks for bringing up this issue.

Ron Yeh

Comment: Thanks Ron, yes you are correct that thumbnail was not in my S3 bucket hence the 'key does not exist' error. I have made sure that the thumbs are there now but they are still not showing in the 3D wall. I have looked at my crossdomain policy file at transcodedvideo.s3.amazonaws.com and it reads - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "adobe.com/xml/dtds/…; <cross-domain-policy> <allow-access-from domain="*.cooliris.com" /> </cross-domain-policy> Is this correct?