# Cooliris wall does not play videos

Tags: .net, video, cooliris

I am using Cooliris wall to show feed from picasa web album.

The photos is shown very well, while the videos are not played at all (all video types).

I read some posts about crossdomain xml , but I still don't know how to make it work.
I read also a suggestion to download the steam (as I understand) but this option is refused die to performance and cost ([Cooliris wall fed by Picassa web albums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179433/cooliris-wall-fed-by-picassa-web-albums?s=61e2b83a-0fbb-44b1-82eb-761406aaab58#new-answer)) 
Some posts mentioned that it is work with slideshow, but in my case it is not played at all ([FLV video not playing in Cooliris embed wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674240/flv-video-not-playing-in-cooliris-embed-wall))

Notes: -I am using DOT NET
-The site hosted at AWS

Comment: Have you checked here: http://www.cooliris.com/developer/documentation/ ?

Comment: Yes and I find nothing about how to fix this issue